# How to reshape data with colnames with year

Tags: r, reshape

Example data frame

```
df <- data.frame(countrycode=c("A","B","C"),
                 hdi_1999 = c(0.7, 0.8, 0.6),
                 hdi_2000 = c(0.71, 0.81, 0.61),
                 hdi_2001 = c(0.72, 0.82, 0.62),
                 icrg_1999 = c(60, 50, 70),
                 icrg_2000 = c(61, 51, 71),
                 icrg_2001 = c(62, 52, 72))
```

What I need is 4 columns  with unique countrycode-year,where year is the number after `_` 1999 2000 2001.

```
countrycode year hdi icrg
```

My code is

```
df_new <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("hdi"),
               names_to = c("hdi", "year"),
               names_sep = "_",
               values_to = "hdi_value",
               names_repair = "unique") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("icrg"),
               names_to = c("icrg", "year"),
               names_sep = "_",
               values_to = "icrg_value",
               names_repair = "unique")
```

Which the result is not unique countrycode-year pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uisng `reshape`.

```
df |> reshape(idvar=1, direction='long', varying=list(2:4, 5:7), sep=' ', 
              v.names=c('hdi', 'icrg'), times=1999:2001)
#         countrycode time icrg hdi
# A.1999           A 1999 0.70   60
# B.1999           B 1999 0.80   50
# C.1999           C 1999 0.60   70
# A.2000           A 2000 0.71   61
# B.2000           B 2000 0.81   51
# C.2000           C 2000 0.61   71
# A.2001           A 2001 0.72   62
# B.2001           B 2001 0.82   52
# C.2001           C 2001 0.62   72
```

Answer (score 1):

We can simply do this in `pivot_longer` itself

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, cols = -countrycode, 
   names_to = c(".value", "year"), names_pattern = "(.*)_(\\d{4})$")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  countrycode year    hdi  icrg
  <chr>       <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A           1999   0.7     60
2 A           2000   0.71    61
3 A           2001   0.72    62
4 B           1999   0.8     50
5 B           2000   0.81    51
6 B           2001   0.82    52
7 C           1999   0.6     70
8 C           2000   0.61    71
9 C           2001   0.62    72
```

Comment: how about the colname "hdi_f_2000", names_sep is not work.

Comment: @LuYip then use `names_pattern` as in the update.  I would suggest to provide reproducible example that matches your original data.